# Media Player <object> - catch mouse events

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to catch mouse events on my media player  within javascript but no success. I also enabled 'SendMouseClickEvents' but still nothing.

```
<object click="das();" id="Player' + j +'" width="160" height="120" ';
                            s +='   classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" ';
                            s +='   type="application/x-oleobject"> ';
                            s +='   <param name="openState" value="wmposMediaOpen">';
                            s +='   <param name="URL" value="inserts/' + sFileName + '"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="captioningID" value="videoCaptions"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="AutoStart" value="1"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="PlayCount" value="1"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="Rate" value="1"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="uiMode" value="none"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="enableContextMenu" value="1"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="stretchToFit" value="0"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="mute" value="true"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="SendMouseClickEvents" value="1"/> ';
                            s +='   <param name="SendMouseMoveEvents" value="1"/> ';
                            s +='</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure whether this is really possible...

try changing the first line from

```
<object click="das();" ...>
```

to:

```
<object onclick="das();" ...>
```

As far as i remember, the attribute is called onclick...

regards